# Auto resize items knowing max number of rows

Tags: html, css

I have a widget that may contain a varied number of items (they are automatically generated), from 1 to 12 items. So my initial setup was to set 3 items per row, therefore having a maximum of 4 rows (12/3):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Since the number of items can change, when there are between 1-6 items it may look ugly because the height of the widget change drastically. So my question, is possible to have an auto resize of items width in order to try to fill the widget as soon as possible?

For example, if you have one item, item width will be 100%, and one row is filled. Two, three, four items, all width 100% and the four expected rows are filled. When five items are present, two items will be 50% and the rest 100%. Six items are present, four items will be 50% and the rest 100%. And so on.. , until you come up on the standard view, 3 items for row.

I'm interested in a plain CSS solution, I think that with flex properties should be possible but I didn't find anything about.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you really just need to add the flex-grow property and change your width to min-width.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 30%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```